# GeoNetwork behind authenticated proxy

Tags: geonetwork, proxy

I'm setting up GeoNetwork behind a HTTP proxy with basic authentication. After setting the proxy_host/port/username/password in the UI, log file says :

```
ERROR [geonetwork] - Proxy credentials cannot be used
```

The user interface is then somewhat laggy and unstable. Log file reports various Exceptions related to HTTP , for example:

```
handleException /geonetwork/proxy org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to secure.geonames.org:443 [secure.geonames.org/5.9.41.208] failed: Connection timed out: connect
```

Problem looks similar whether I use GeoNetwork 3.x or 4.x. System is Windows Server 2019 with java 1.8.

Having a look into the source code, the [proxy setup for http client](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/blob/2a0be27d39990cb71a48bbb40208f4482308c23a/core/src/main/java/org/fao/geonet/lib/NetLib.java#L170) ignores proxy credentials.

Any suggestion or workaround ?

Comment: Edit the source code to take the proxy credentials in to account and submit a PR to GeoNetwork

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by temporarily adding the credentials to the host field like

```
<proxyuser>:<proxypassword>@<proxyhost>
```

which seems to work for most connections, but is probably unsafe (e.g. for the field is stored in plain text). What does not work is harvesting by CSW: [Proxy server with credetinals causes 407](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/issues/590). And there are several open issues concerning proxy with auth, e.g. [Proxy credentials exposed in plain text](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/issues/5619).

Comment: This syntax for host field does not seem to work (for example when retrieving data from thesaurus URLs). Did you set the proxy host parameter into the admin GUI or in the -D java flags ?

Comment: I did add the credentials (url-encoded!) in the host field of the admin gui's settings panel and was able to access my productive setting on the web. Testing on version is 4.0.5. However, if geonetwork is the only app on the server it might be worth trying to add the proxy settings to CATALINA_OPTS (-Dhttp.proxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=<host> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<port> -Dhttp.proxyUser=<user> -Dhttp.proxyPassword=<pass> -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=<no_proxy_host1|no_proxy_host2>). Could you discdibe how you reproduce the error with the thesaurus exactly so I can check?

Comment: I reproduced the error on 4.0.5 : setting _proxyuser:proxypassword@proxyhost_ in the proxy host field. Got the following GUI message when adding a thesaurus from URL ([example SKOS URL](http://www.vie-publique.fr/sites/default/files/medias/vp-thesaurus-skos.rdf)) : _error importing thesaurus, unknownhost exception, proxyuser:proxypassword@proxyhost invalid IPv6 adress._  (it may be confused by the fact my proxyuser is an integer). I will try the -D options again, but I'm afraid the way the code handles proxy parameters takes precedence over JVM parameters.

Comment: I see. But what if you set the proxy in the CATALINA_OPTS and have tomcat handle the proxy while disabling it in geonetwork?
Your thesaurus URL unfortunatelly refuses connection, so I can't test:
Connect to www.vie-publique.fr:80 [www.vie-publique.fr/160.92.103.252] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Comment: Unfortunately I am not running on Tomcat : I am running the zip package provided with a jetty webserver. Do you mean it is possible to delegate proxy management to Tomcat (especially basic auth) ? Then it could be worth a try. By the way, the example thesaurus URL is now online.

Comment: I checked again and I can now confirm the url is reachable. However, Geonetwork persists throwing a "Connect to www.vie-publique.fr:80 [www.vie-publique.fr/160.92.103.252] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)" with the proxy settings in the catalina opts only, but was able to import the thesaurus successfully with the proxy settings enabled in the settings gui as well.